# Floating menu, how to stick menu to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm relatively new to js and fighting with floating menu.

This is how my js code look like

```
$(function(){
 console.log('jest');
 $(window).scroll(function(event){
  console.log($('#menu').offset().top, $(this).scrollTop());
    if ($('#menu').offset().top <= $(this).scrollTop()+$(window).height()) {
                 $('#menu').addClass("fixed");
       } else {
           $('#menu').removeClass("fixed");
       }
  });
});
```

When the top is achieved, `fixed` class is added properly.

My question is:
What should I do inside `fixed` class to make the menu stick to the top?

Comment: There is a position "sticky", that does this without any JS.

Comment: @Keith it does not change anything when I added 'sticky', but thanks for your hint

Comment: Look at my snippet for a working example, don't forget to set `top: 0` when using `sticky`.  Nice thing with sticky, is you can also have multiple ones, and there also part of document flow, unlike fixed.  eg. say you wanted a header to stay at top, and when you get to the bottom another header takes over, it's very simple to do.

Comment: Okey, it was my mistake. Sticky worked correctly. It was really suprising. Thanks a lot

Comment: No, problem.  If you can accept my answer that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice an simple "position: sticky"..

```css
brand {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

header {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

section {
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<brand>
<div>This is our branding,.  It can scroll away.</div>
<small>for all your header needs,.. </small>
</brand>

<header>
This is the header
</header>
<section>
Our othe stuff can go in here.<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Scroll down<br><br><br><br><br><br>
Even further<br><br><br><br><br>
A little bit more<br><br><br><br><br>
Ok I'm bored now.
</section>

<header>
This is repeated, see how the header takes over
</header>
<section>
Our othe stuff can go in here.<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Scroll down<br><br><br><br><br><br>
Even further<br><br><br><br><br>
A little bit more<br><br><br><br><br>
Ok I'm bored now.
</section>
```

Comment: FYI: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky  (as of now, available in latest browsers, not IE11)

Comment: @freedomn-m  Pollyfill's are available if IE11 and older are required. This one works all the way back to IE9 -> https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill

Answer (score 0):

```
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not the best solution I guess, since it's added immediately after scroll, and for some reason the class is not removed ahen we scroll up:(